# 2 Foreign Keys in Entity Framework Code First Approach

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

I am creating an application in MVC 5, Visual Studio 2013, EF 6 (Code First Approach). I have implemented Identity and working fine. Now I want to create a table in which I need 2 foreign key relationships - One from dbo.AspNetUsers and another from 2nd table (Lets name it Table2).

In my IdentityModel.cs, I have following code:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public DbSet<Table2> Table2 { get; set; }

    public ApplicationDbContext() : base("ConnectionString", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }
}
```

and this is my table2:

```
[Key]
[Display(Name = "ID")]
public int ID { get; set; }

[Required]
[StringLength(200, MinimumLength = 10)]
[Display(Name = "Col1")]
public string Col1{ get; set; }

[Required]
[StringLength(4000, MinimumLength = 10)]
[Display(Name = "Col2")]
public string Col2 { get; set; }
```

Now, I need to create a table (NewTable) in which there are 2 foreign keys - UserID(from dbo.AspNetUsers) and another from Table2.

Can anyone tell me how I can do that? I have Googled it but have not been able to find any satisfactory answer.

Answer (score 0):

It is simple, just create a Navigation property.

Example:

```
public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
```

**EDIT:**

I would recommend merging the two DB Context. As In the long run it will avoid many issues. Example:

```
public class MyDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public MyDbContext () : base("DbConn",false) {

        }

        public MyDbContext (string connectionString):base(connectionString,false)
        {

        }
        public DbSet<Table1> MyTable1{ get; set; }
        public DbSet<Table2> MyTable2{ get; set; }
   }
```

Comment: I have applied it but it will create a foreign key for dbo.AspNetUsers only (I think). If I apply the same code for Table2, I would be needing to create another DbContext class (as I am using ApplicationDbContext class). But while creating Views, I am required to specify a Context Class and at the time, which contex class will I specify.

Comment: I would suggest merging both DB Contexts into one. Please check the edit.